# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying now to develop my first Windows Forms Application.

```
 public partial class AddCourse : Form
 {
    Course course;
    public AddCourse(Course course)
    {
        this.course = course;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The problem here is that I get an error.

*Error  CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Course' is less accessible than method 'AddCourse.AddCourse(Course)'*

I know that this usually happens when a private variable is being called in a public method. But in my example I just do not know where the problem is.

I do have a sample code that is similar to this one and it runs just fine.

Anyone who can tell me what I am missing?

Comment: may be your class Course is Private . try public Class Course {}

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your class isnt public

```
public class Course {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the **type** `Course` public; i.e.

```
public class Course {...}
```

If a public method on a public type takes parameters: all of those parameters must be public. Otherwise callers can't possibly understand the API.

Comment: This does not work as I access this here

`AddCourse form = new AddCourse(course);`

And there are no errors.

Comment: @FGpier what do you mean "this does not work"? the error you have described is a very common one and stems from having a non-public type on a public API. Which is *exactly* what you are doing here. What happens when you make `Course` public?

Comment: My course class was public. I am sorry, I should have pasted this code as well
`public class Course
 {
  protected XmlDocument root;
  protected XmlNode coursenode;
  protected XmlNode nameattr;
}
`
This does not fix the error. 
How is it possible to work on the other project I have and it does not work on mine? The code is the same and the desigh is the same(the names of textfields, buttons, etc). Do you know what may I be missing?

Comment: @FGpier is `Course` perhaps *nested* inside a non-public class? i.e. `class Something { ... public class Course { ... } ... }`?

Comment: Its inside a namespace

`namespace GradePredictionTool
{
    public enum Level
    {
        LEVEL_4 = 4,
        LEVEL_5 = 5,
        LEVEL_6 = 6,
    }
    class Course
    {
        protected XmlDocument root;
        protected XmlNode coursenode;
        protected XmlNode nameattr;

        public Course(XmlDocument root, XmlNode coursenode)
        {
            this.root = root;
            this.coursenode = coursenode;
            this.nameattr = this.coursenode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
            mergeLevels();
        }
.
.
.
`